# Problem formating 2TB HDD

Tags: server, 16.10, fdisk, parted

I'm trying to create a 2TB partition on a WD Blue HDD (WD20EZRZ), I believe the issue is that the partition table isn't being written to the drive because after I use `parted` and `print` I see

```
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

If I do the process of:
1. `sudo parted /dev/sda`
2. `mklabel gpt`
3. `unit TB`
4. `mkpart primary 0.00TB 2.00TB`
5. `print`

Returns:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2.00TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
1       0.00TB  2.00TB  2.00TB               primary
```

After I quit `parted` and `fdisk -l` or `lsblk` `/dev/sda1` isn't created.

FYI: `/dev/sda` is the WB Blue 2TB & `/dev/sdb` is a Sandisk 120GB SSD which is the bootable disk.

I've done the similar sort of task in `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` but I have the same issue as above.

Comment: I have never used parted, just gparted. But you do not have the format included? `sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt mkpart P1 ext4 0.00TB 2.00TB` But if using gpt, I might use gdisk. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: I've tried to use `gdisk` but it seems it still doesn't write the partition table to the disk. Should I try to partition the drive in windows and format it there to `NTFS`?

Comment: I have seen Windows not do it correctly. I would not suggest using it. Are you formatting the partition you create. And what version are you using fdisk before 16.04 did not support gpt, so would not show it correctly. What does `sudo parted -l` or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` show?